# sorting CONTENT_FILTER_URI results

Tags: java, android, listview, android-cursorloader

I was going through the basic tutorial on the Google Android Developer website for [Retrieving a List of Contacts](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html#GeneralMatch). *Section: Matching any type*.

I've setup my listview and it displays the search results as expected, except that I want to sort by display name **(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY)**. Currently it's just a seemingly random mess.

The code in question is as follows:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    /*
     * Appends the search string to the base URI. Always
     * encode search strings to ensure they're in proper
     * format.
     */
    Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(mSearchString));
    // Starts the query
    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            contentUri,
            PROJECTION,
            null,
            null,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY // <- SORT THIS, PLEASE!
    );
}
```

When I use **Contacts.CONTENT_URI** as my contentUri to display all contacts, the sort works correctly as expected.

Why is it not working for the filtered results?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to answer my own question!

Looking at the example Google code, I managed to find the line:

```
final static String SORT_ORDER =
                Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
```

So, I need to use **Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY** on devices > Honeycomb,
and **Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME** on devices < Honeycomb.

some example code for those that don't understand:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    /*
     * Appends the search string to the base URI. Always
     * encode search strings to ensure they're in proper
     * format.
     */
    Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(mSearchString));

    String sortOrder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
        sortOrder = Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY;
    }
    else
    {
        sortOrder = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    }

    // Starts the query
    return new CursorLoader(
            getActivity(),
            contentUri,
            PROJECTION,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder // Sorted by name
    );
}
```

I tested it and it works. Hope this helps anyone else.